# Calcular horas trabajadas

Tags: c#, mysql

que tal, estoy realizando un programa en c# que muestra el horario de los empleados de una tienda en una semana, y además calcula las horas trabajadas, el problema o lo que no he podido calcular correctamente son las horas trabajadas, ya que tengo dos tablas en una bd en mysql, la tabla horarios y la tabla checada.

La tabla horarios tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
TIENDA | EMPLEADO | FECHA | E1 | S1 | E2 | S2 |
```

Tienda es el número de tienda a la que pertenece el empleado.

Empleado es la clave con la que se identifica a un empleado

La fecha es asignada por día y `E1` `S1` `E2` `S2` son las horas de entrada y salida.

Por ejemplo a un empleado se le puede asignar el horario del día 21/07/2016 en donde entre a las 10:00 am, salga a comer a las 14:00, regrese de comida a las 16:00 y salga a las 21:00.

Ahora en la tabla checada se tiene:

```
TIENDA | FECHA | FHORA | EMPLEADO | TIPO | HUELLA
```

`FHORA` es la fecha junta con la hora exacta de checada del empleado.

`TIPO` indica si es entrada o salida

`Huella` si checó con lector de huella o con clave.

Mi problema es que tengo que calcular las horas reales trabajadas, sé que tengo que relacionar la fecha del horario asignado con la fecha de la tabla checada, lo que no sé cómo hacer es guardar las horas de entrada y salida para que me las vaya sumando y al final me muestre las horas reales que trabajó un empleado.

(En caso de que un empleado no haya checado, por ejemplo, su hora de regreso de comida, no se le asigna hora)

Espero haberme explicado y me puedan ayudar, gracias :)

Comment: un empleado puede ingresar a trabajar en distintas tiendas? lo pregunto porque sino el columna tienda en la tabla de horario no hace falta, la tiene donde trabaja se asocia al empleado (seria un dato de su legajo)

Comment: Los empleados son re-ubicados cada cierto tiempo a diferentes tiendas, además pueden checar desde otras tiendas, pero el problema es que yo no le puedo hacer cambios a la bd, puesto que así lo tienen determinado en donde trabajo :(

Comment: ¿Quién hace la consulta a la base de datos? ¿La haces tú misma, o sólo recibes datos de una consulta que hace alguien más? Y si la hace alguien más, ¿recibes sólo los datos de las columnas (sin operaciones, formatos, etc.)?

Comment: Yo hago un select que me trae todos los campos de la tabla checada y filtro de acuerdo al número de tienda y un rango de fechas

Answer (score 0):

```
Tipo Entrada = date Fhora  
hEntrada1 = Fhora;    
Tipo Salida =  Fhora
hSalida1 = Fhora;
```

Si la Fecha es la misma

Deberias tener 2 entradas y dos salidas

```
hTrabajadaJornada1 = datediff( hSalida - hEntrada);

hTrabajadaJornada2 = datediff(Entrada - Salida);

HorasTRabajadasDiarias =  suma(hTrabajadaJornada 1 + hTrabajada2);
```

espero haber explicado bien.

Comment: Ok, me queda claro, pero en caso de que el empleado no haya checado una de las jornadas, se quedaría en cero?

Comment: esto no compila ni a la de 3...

Comment: @MiquelColl Tranquilo, puede ser aceptado como pseudocodigo

Comment: @MiquelColl no busco que me den la respuesta en código, sino que me den una idea de cómo hacerlo, porque estoy pérdida en ese aspecto.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo realizar esto desde la consulta a la base de datos (explicación más abajo):

(SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b5b3/12)

```
select
    h.tienda,
    h.empleado,
    h.fecha,
    ce1.fhora as hora_entrada_1,
    cs1.fhora as hora_salida_1,
    ce2.fhora as hora_entrada_2,
    cs2.fhora as hora_salida_2,
    DATE_FORMAT(timediff(convert(DATE_FORMAT(cs1.fhora,'%H:%i:%s'), time),
        convert(DATE_FORMAT(ce1.fhora,'%H:%i:%s'), time)),'%H:%i:%s') as diferencia_1,
    DATE_FORMAT(timediff(convert(DATE_FORMAT(cs2.fhora,'%H:%i:%s'), time),
        convert(DATE_FORMAT(ce2.fhora,'%H:%i:%s'), time)),'%H:%i:%s') as diferencia_2

    from horarios h
    left join checada ce1
        on ce1.empleado = h.empleado
    and ce1.tipo = 'ENTRADA'
    and ce1.fhora = (SELECT fhora
                    from checada c
                    where c.empleado = ce1.empleado
                    and c.fecha = ce1.fecha
                    and c.tipo = ce1.tipo
                    ORDER BY fhora asc
                    limit 1)
    left join checada cs1
        on cs1.empleado = h.empleado
        and cs1.tipo = 'SALIDA'
        and cs1.fhora = (SELECT fhora
                        from checada c
                        where c.empleado = cs1.empleado
                        and c.fecha = cs1.fecha
                        and c.tipo = cs1.tipo
                        ORDER BY fhora asc
                        limit 1)

    left join checada ce2
    on ce2.empleado = h.empleado
    and ce2.tipo = 'ENTRADA'
    and ce2.fhora = (SELECT fhora
                    from checada c
                    where c.empleado = ce2.empleado
                    and c.fecha = ce2.fecha
                    and c.tipo = ce2.tipo
                    ORDER BY fhora desc
                    limit 1)
    left join checada cs2
    on cs2.empleado = h.empleado
    and cs2.tipo = 'SALIDA'
    and cs2.fhora = (SELECT fhora
                    from checada c
                    where c.empleado = cs2.empleado
                    and c.fecha = cs2.fecha
                    and c.tipo = cs2.tipo
                    ORDER BY fhora desc
                    limit 1)

order by empleado ASC;
```

Separé las horas de entrada y salida de cada día usando `JOIN`, asumiendo que como máximo serán dos entradas y dos salidas por empleado por día. Luego calculé las diferencias de tiempo entre la primera entrada y primera salida, y entre la segunda entrada y la segunda salida. Luego sólo tendrías que sumar en tu aplicación ambas diferencias y te da el tiempo total por día por cada empleado.

Como consideración, si el empleado sólo sale y entra una vez, las horas de entrada y de salida van a ser iguales. Dentro de la aplicación tendrías que compararlas, y si son iguales, sólo tomar la primera diferencia y no sumar la segunda.

Me disculpo si la consulta es muy larga/ineficiente. No tengo mucha experiencia en MySQL, la verdad, ni tengo mucho tiempo en este minuto para analizarla demasiado.

Espero que te haya quedado claro y que te sirva.

Comment: Ok, la voy a probar y ver si funciona, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder :)

Comment: Sólo una pregunta, eso de ce1, cs1, ce2, cs2 de dónde sale?

Comment: @Sandra Son alias para las tablas. Como estoy haciendo JOIN a la misma tabla varias veces, es necesario para distinguirlas. ce1 = Checada Entrada 1; ce2 = Checada Entrada 2; cs1 = Checada Salida 1; cs2 = Checada Salida 2

Comment: Gracias por la consulta, pero es muy lenta, tendré que seguir buscando cómo adaptarla :).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando no se chequea una segunda entrada y salida, los valores ¿En la BD están en un valor por defecto que permita comprobarlo verdad?, es preciso. O eso, o algo que permita saber que no hubo segundo periodo. Yo no programo en mysql, pero visto que solo quieres saber como hacerlo.. Hay un tipo de estructura en C# llamada TimeSpan que puede contener periodos de tiempo, perfecta para lo que necesitas.

Entonces cuando no chequée el segundo horario, las variables DateTime correspondientes a la segunda entrada y salida, deberán estár las 2 **en la misma e identica fecha y hora**, (preestablecida antes de hacer las dos asignaciones), es importante porque así, al restar sale 0 horas, que es lo correcto en ese caso). Has de usar para esto 4 variables DateTime, a las que les asignarás los valores tal como he indicado, y que pasarás al metodo.

*Nota : DateTime es una variable especial, contiene fecha y hora necesariamente, cuando asignes los valores a los DateTime, habrás de asignarles fecha y hora completas.*

***Sugiero este código (C#) (comprobado) ..***

```
    using System;

    internal decimal horasTrabajadas_HorarioPartido(DateTime check1_entrada, DateTime check1_salida, DateTime check2_entrada, DateTime check2_salida)
    {
    TimeSpan tiempoTrabajado = check1_salida.Subtract(check1_entrada).Duration();

    tiempoTrabajado += check2_salida.Subtract(check2_entrada).Duration();

    // Esta siguiente opcion de comentario, devolvería solo hora completas ...

    // return tiempoTrabajado.TotalHours;

    return decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(tiempoTrabajado.TotalMinutes/60),1);
    }
```

Este metodo devolvería las horas trabajadas con un decimal, para no eliminar las fracciones de hora. ( 8.5 horas = 8 horas 30 minutos ). Si quieres que devuelva horas enteras (completas), puedes sustituir la linea de return por la otra linea de return que está justo encima como comentario y cambiar el tipo de valor que devuelve el método (que está como decimal), por int.

Visto lo que me comentas, te sugiero, quen en el codigo con el que hagas la consulta, pases las horas de chequeo a string, y compruebes que valor adoptan en caso de estar vacías (quizá una cadena vacía "" o lo que sea). Luego si al hacer una consulta y comprobar las horas de chequeo, faltan alguno de los 2 primeros valores (primer chequeo de entrada o primer chequeo de salida) que devuelva un correspondiente error en el calculo de horas, indicando que faltan datos para poder realizar el calculo de horas trabajadas; Y en caso de que falte una de las dos segundas, chequeo de entrada y de salida, devuelvas un correspondiente error indicando el hecho de que falta el valor que sea.

Otra manera que puedes ver, es la posibilidad de detallar cuales son los datos que faltan en el registro, devolviendo cada uno de los datos de los chequeos del registro en detalle, en lugar de devolver un calculo de horas,  a parte de indicar que no es posible hacer un calculo fiable de las horas trabajadas porque faltan datos en el registro, así quedará todo lo más claro posible.

Comment: No, de hecho esa es otra de mis dudas, porque si el empleado no checa alguna hora no se guarda nada, por ejemplo, si el empleado olvidó checar a la primer salida, en la bd, sólo aparecen la primer entrada, la segunda entrada y la segunda salida.

Comment: ¿Y que como te han indicado que lo debe resolver la aplicación? ¿O no te han dicho que hacer en ese caso? .. Si no hay un dato, no se puede calcular ese periodo, y el conteo de ese día seguramente no será correcto. Si un dato es correcto y el otro se asigna por defecto dará un calculo de horas erroneo. De modo que si falta un dato debes asignar la entrada y salida iguales por defecto, para que cuente 0 horas, y si no hay un primer y segundo datos reales (al menos un primer periodo del día), debe dar un error indicando que faltan datos en ese registro.

Comment: A mí solo me dijeron que tenía que mostrar las horas reales trabajadas de acuerdo a las horas de checada, pero justo ese ha sido mi dolor de cabeza, qué no se cómo sumarlas cuando no hay pares.